# C Passing Complex Structures by Reference to Functions

Tags: c, data-structures, cuda, compiler-errors

I replicated the guidance provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370047/passing-struct-to-function) but continue receiving the following error for each line with a function header and prototype: 'typedef "Neuron" may not be used in an elaborated type specifier'.  I researched this error and didn't find much useful content.  Any help would be most appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct neuronHead {
  int x, y, z;                    
  neuronHead *apical[25];  
  neuronHead *basal[25];    
  neuronHead *axon[25];      
  int time;                       
} neuron;

typedef struct neuron Neuron;

void setupBrain(struct Neuron ****brain); /* brain is a 3D array of structs */
void freeBrain(struct Neuron ****brain);

int main(void) {
   Neuron ***brain;

   setupBrain(&brain);
   freeBrain(&brain); }

void setupBrain(struct Neuron ****brain) {
   /* code for malloc'ing a 3D array of structures */ }

void freeBrain(struct Neuron ****brain) {
   /* code for freeing the 3D array of structures */ }
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 and using Nvidia's NVCC compiler to run the code on GPUs, though this shouldn't be relevant to the error at hand.

Comment: One good style to write those structs is:  ``typedef struct Neuron_tag { ... } Neuron_t;``

Comment: Neuron is not `typedef`, not a `struct` tag. Do not put `struct` before it in the parameter list.

Comment: I used to append _t to my types. Don't do it, it's specifically reserved for POSIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
typedef struct neuron Neuron;
```

with

```
typedef struct neuronHead Neuron;
```

When writing

```
struct neuronHead { ... } neuron;
```

you introduce two elements:

- a compound data type named "struct neuronHead",
- and a variable named "neuron" having type "struct neuronHead".

Typedefs allow to create aliases for *data types*:

```
typedef <original_type> <alias_type>;
```

while in your example an <original_type> (struct neuron) is not a proper type. Proper type definitions are both:

```
struct neuronHead { ... } neuron; /* data type AND variable were introduced */
typedef struct neuronHead Neuron; /* data type introduced */
```

and:

```
typedef struct neuronHead { ... } Neuron; /* data type AND type alias were introduced */
```

Sample usage of pre-defined types:

```
struct neuronHead n1; /* correct */
Neuron            n2; /* also correct */
struct neuron     n3; /* incorrect: 'neuron' is variable name! */
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for untangling my spaghetti struct code.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no `struct neuron` you can typedef to. In your case, `neuron` is a global variable of type `struct neuronHead`.

You need to change your code to

```
struct neuronHead {
  int x, y, z;                    
  struct neuronHead *apical[25];  
  struct neuronHead *basal[25];    
  struct neuronHead *axon[25];      
  int time;                       
};

typedef struct neuronHead Neuron;
```

or,

```
typedef struct neuronHead Neuron;

struct neuronHead {
  int x, y, z;                    
  Neuron *apical[25];  
  Neuron *basal[25];    
  Neuron *axon[25];      
  int time;                       
};
```

or,

```
  typedef struct neuronHead {
  int x, y, z;                    
  struct neuronHead *apical[25];  
  struct neuronHead *basal[25];    
  struct neuronHead *axon[25];      
  int time;                       
} Neuron;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an instance of an `int`:

```
int some_int;
```

In `C`, in general, the syntax is:

```
<type> <variable_name>
```

When you have written something like this:

```
struct Thing {
    int i;
    /* Other members... */
} thing;
```

What this actually means is: *create a variable, named `thing`, which is of type `struct Thing`, and this structure is defined as follows: `{ int i; /* Other members... */ }`*.

Then you do something like this:

```
typedef struct thing SomeThing;
```

At this point, it makes no sense, as you are trying to `typedef` an instance (`thing`).

What you probably meant was something like this:

```
struct Thing {
    int i;
    /* Other members... */
}; /* Nothing here! It's the end of type definition. */

typedef struct Thing thing; /* Typedef "struct Thing" -> "thing". */
```

The general syntax for `typedef` is:

```
typedef <original_type> <new_alias>
```

So it can be made shorter:

```
typedef /* Typedef the following struct... */
    struct Thing {
        int i;
        /* Other members... */
    }
thing; /* ... to such a name. */
```

Then you can correctly use `thing` as a variable type.

**Also**: There are no references in `C`, just the pointers.