# what's the difference between the two statements?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I wrote the following code, there is some difference exist but I can't figure it out.

```
typedef struct {
    char* ch;   
    int length;
}Hstring;
```

```
int Strlength(Hstring* s) {
    return s->length; // if I use s.length there, error occurs.
}
```

```
int Strlength(Hstring s) {
    return s.length; // if I use s->length there, error occurs.
}
```

So what the differences between the two types? Will I get the same result? and why those errors occur?

Comment: Practically? There's really no difference between the two functions. And if you wonder about the difference between `.` and `->` to access structure members (which seems to be your big problem), note that one argument is a *pointer* and the other is *not*. And reread whatever text-book you have.

Comment: Also see [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c/2575050), and a ton of similar questions here on SO.

Comment: @Some programmer dude OK, it looks like they are rules needed to be remembered. but I still have a little question, what the meaning of the name of a struct variable(is it a pointer to itself or meaningless)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is dot (`.`) and arrow (`->`) operators.

You can only use the dot (`.`) operator with a structure or union variable to access its members.

You can only use the arrow (`->`) operator with a pointer variable to access members of the structure or union the pointer points to.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answers that state that dot (`.`) is for 'normal' variables and arrow (`->`) is for pointers, note that arrow is a syntactic equivalent to a pointer de-reference followed by a dot, provided for convenience (since it's such a common operation).

```
Hstring* s;
s->length;   // this is equivalent to...
(*s).length; // ...this
```

The parentheses are needed since dot has a higher precedence than star.  Without them, you'd be a) using a dot with a pointer and b) trying to de-reference the integer length field, both of which would be invalid.

```
Hstring* s;
*s.length;   // this is equivalent to...
*(s.length); // ...this (not what you want at all)
```

Comment: Also, the reverse is true. Given `Hstring s`, `s.length` is equivalent to `( &s )->length`.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the `.` operator is for accessing members of a **struct**, whereas the `->` operator is for accessing members of a **struct pointer**.

However, another important difference between your two functions is that in `Strlength(Hstring* s)` the parameter is passed **by reference**, implying that the function operates on the "original" memory location of the data structure and therefore can modify its contents.

In contrast, in `Strlength(Hstring s)` the parameter is passed **by value**, implying that the function operates on a copy of the original structure and changes made within the function will not be visible outside the function.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555817/12056564).

Answer (score 0):

`*s` is a pointer, you may reference the members using operator `->`, if there's no `*`, it's just a variable, you may reference the members using operator (dot) `.`